# What events are fired on changing tab away and to a page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an image slider that slides automatically. Because I'm nice, I want to ensure that it doesn't continue to slide when the user has a different window/tab focused.

What events fire when leaving a tab/window, and which fire when returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When leaving: `blur`; when entering: `focus`. Additionally, the following can happen:

- `click` when the user clicks on the window to get focus;
- `mouseover` when the user moves over the window;
- `mousedown`/`mouseup` (related to clicking);
- `keyup`/`keydown` when pressing a key (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>).

Comment: So if I triggered the slider to stop on when window is blurred and start when window is focussed, it should work?

Comment: @Lekensteyn if I use "blur", it will activate when I hit the address bar, which is undesired. Any workarounds?

Comment: @rebelliard The blur event will always fire, there is no way to distinguish focusing the location bar or some other component not in the page. In the context of this question, you could overlay a small button on the page to continue the animation.